# VMware ESXi 5.1 can be installed RAID1 Software?

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, software-raid

I am close to get a dedicated server in some data center and in the shopping cart there is no option to RAID1 Hardware only RAID1 by Software, since they will install ESXi it's possible that ESXi can run a software to emulate a hardware RAID1? how it will affect the performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is not possible. VMware ESXi can live on a non-RAID disk or a hardware RAID solution, but has no provision for software RAID.

I would contact the provider and express your intentions to see what they have that could meet VMware's [hardware requirements](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=io).

Comment: Thanks @ewwhite I discovered that all the budget servers are not able to use hardware RAID, I checked in SoftLayer, PhoenixNap and NetDepot datacenters and some of them still work with ESXi 5.0 no 5.1

About the enterprise RAID performance I found in many forums that “do you have write-back turned on?” it's usually the answer, so the hardware RAID must have the write-back feature for the best performance... I hope this info help new users